# Unity3D - Limiting 3rd person view to only see what the FPS view can see

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame-rate, lighting

I'm working on an FPS game in Unity3D where the user can switch to a third person view. However, while in that third person view, they need to only be able to see the things they could have seen while in first person view if they turned 360 degrees.

[Diagram of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv4iy.png)

**What would be the best way to achieve this?** I was thinking of using a light somehow with a multiply effect, so that anything the light touches becomes visible, and everything else is hidden.

Regards,
Fynn

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian Lague has a good tutorial on how to achieve this effect:
https://youtu.be/rQG9aUWarwE